# Issue with calling JavaScript in Jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to call a function that is in javascript inside Jquery once a link is clicked.  When I try and do this nothing happens.

Code:

```
function run(){
    var url = '/pcg/popups/grabnotes.php';
    showUrlInDialog(url);
}

$("#NotesAccessor").click(function () {
      run();
    });
```

PHP:

```
..
echo "<a href='#' id='NotesAccessor'>Click to access</a>";
..
```

Not to sure why, I check my calling in the debug and nothing gets called.  From the run function it goes to a Jquery UI dialog that will open up.  It just does not get to that point.

If you could give me a hand I would appreciate it!

Comment: How many elements have an id of `NotesAccessor`? Also, do you get any errors in your JS console?

Comment: None just that one, no.  I just debug it in Chrome.

Comment: Are you wrapping your jQuery in a document.ready call?

Comment: No I am not I forgot to do that.

Comment: You should use `$("#NotesAccessor").click(run);` (but that isn't the problem). Only wrap the function you want to call when an event fires if you want to pass arguments.

Comment: Note that all of the (non-PHP) code that you show is JavaScript. There  is no magic trick to "calling JavaScript in Jquery" because all of jQuery is JavaScript.

Comment: @Oriol If you're going to comment on how the code should be improved, why not drop jQuery altogether and use `<a href="javascript:run();">Click to access</a>`?

Comment: @Oriol I did not know you could to that.

Comment: @DavidBiga - what made the difference?

Comment: @j08691 you did....wrapping it in the document.ready call.

Comment: @Kolink Good point, but some people think that `<a href="javascript:run();">` is obtrusive JavaScript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably your DOM isn't loaded yet when you define the click event for $("#NotesAccessor").
Wrap your instruction in a $(document).ready handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#NotesAccessor").click(function () {
      run();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem could be because NotesAccessor is an anchor element. You can make NotesAccessor to be a div and with css you make look just like an anchor.

In the other hand you can call to a JavaScript function from an anchor directly something like:

```
<a href:'javascript:run()' >Click to access</a>
```